# How to reduce amount of processes for a Play2 application?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I deployed some internal Play2 applications to a server.

Since it's a development server, it does not have much resources. In top of that, it has to share them with other applications running on it.

[image: Resource usage of the Play2 application]

Using `htop` I see that the app. running on port `9002` was forked something like 20 times. Same thing for the app. running on port `9001`.

So, my first questions are:

- how bad is this? (for the resources of this machine)
- how can I **reduce the amount of processes** per application?

Additionally, it would be great if you could comment on what a recommended **server configuration** would look like (memory/CPU). It's an intranet application and it does not have many concurrent users (one or two, five tops). Most of the time it will just sit idle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not processes, but threads. If you hit `F5`, you will see that they are all children of the main process and if you go to `Setup -> Display Option` and select `Display threads in a different color`, you will also see it by the color.

Comment: Thanks! Would reducing the amount of available threads help in reducing the resource consumption? (memory)

Comment: If that is what you want, yes.

Comment: James Roper from Typesafe answered my mail on the Play mailing-list saying that this amount of threads (aprox. 20) is nothing to worry about. Since they are very lightweight, they pose no big additional memory consumption.